# Is there something like a polymorphic Singleton?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, singleton

I have a resource loader object that loads objects from the disk or from a ZIP archive, depending on the platform.

It has state (e.g. the path to the directory or the ZIP archive, and possibly some caching in the future), so it needs to be a single instance.

So normally, a Singleton would do. But my problem is that this resource loader has multiple implementations, of which one is chosen at initialisation. So turning the resource loader into a Singleton won't do.

All I can think of is to have a Singleton that holds a reference to the single resource loader. But isn't there a nicer pattern for this?

Comment: have the getInstance decide which implementation it initiates instead of a single one

Comment: I don't know c/c++ well so maybe this wouldn't be as easy to implement but in JS that sounds like a job for a singleton-factory pattern. The factory function decides what object to build and returns it or just returns the existing object as needed. I find it makes reorganization of code easier since you don't have to worry about what's in place when you have objects in play that shouldn't be copied but I could see how it might also solve your problem.

Comment: Why would it have to be a singleton? Non-singleton objects can have state just fine.

Comment: When it's a Singleton and contains the path to the ZIP archive then you can handle only one ZIP archive in the entire app. I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: I'd pass an `IResourceLoader` interface via IoC to the classes that need access to resources. That way you can easily use different implementations of that interface, and your classes don't need to know if this happens to be a singleton or not. They're just told "use this resource loader"

Comment: Better to just not have a Singleton, ever.

Comment: I am not convinced what you need is a singelton. But if it was there is not problems in using a factory to create the singelton (if fact I would encourage that so that you can plug in different singeltons based on the situation (thus allowing you to test)).

Comment: You don't need to use the Singleton pattern to have a single instance with a state.

Answer (score 19):

What you want sounds like a good case for the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You would write something like:

```
class LoaderFactory {
  public Loader getLoader() {
    if (environment1) return ZipLoader.getInstance();
    else if (environment2) return DiskLoader.getInstance();
    else return SomeOtherLoader.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Each type of `Loader` class is a singleton, and each should implement the `Loader` interface. Your `LoaderFactory` performs the logic that determines which type is appropriate to return.

Comment: Is it still the GOF factory pattern if a single method decides what to instantiate?

Comment: @futlib Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @futlib why would it matter if it isn't?

Comment: Ironically, if you search Wikipedia for "Factory pattern" you will be redirected to [Factory (object-oriented programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), and not to [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as your link links to; apparently these are two different things. A bit confusing I might say.

Answer (score 2):

This have nothing to do with Singleton pattern.

What you need is some kind of resource manager type that would register factories objects, one for each resource type you want it to be able to provide. Each factory object would know how to load the associated resource type.

Then when you want a resource, you use a function to get the resource from a resource manager instance, that will find the the resource already loaded for you or will request the resource-type-specific factory it owns to load it.

It's interface would look like this (but it really depends on your context in the end):

```
class ResourceManager
{
public:

    template<ResourceType>
    void add_factory( std::shared_ptr<ResourceFactory<ResourceType>> factory );

    template<Resourcetype>
    std::shared_ptr<ResourceType> get(); // will look into registered factories and provide a resource instance if it   

};
```

This is classical way to manage resources gathered in an object.

Once you have such type (a ResourceManager class for example) working, it's easy to make it (or not, as others will suggest) Singleton. I don't recommend it though.

It's not your class that is polymorphic, it's the resource type.

A better way, most of the time, would be to pass a reference to the resource manager instance into functions and types that need it. There are cases where making it a singleton would be better, but it's very rare.

Comment: As I explained, it's not a singleton if you don't make it one. You could have several different resource manager instances if it makes sense for you specific case. Making it singleton is totally another matter.

Comment: @LokiAstari I forgot to  mention yesterday that I changed the formulation to clarify. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are well stated. I just want to impress that polymorphism and singleton are what you might call orthogonal concerns. Polymorphism is more of a concept and how we achieve that concept, while Singleton is defining a pattern and taking advantage of the concept of polymorphism for use cases such as the one you bring up.

Comment: Did you mean "orthogonal" instead of "cross-cutting"?

Comment: Singletons are by definition not polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a use case for an [Inversion of Control (IoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) Container -- they use what's called [Dependency Injection (DI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to create/initialize instances of objects and wire things together for operation.

([This article about IoC Containers and DI](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) might not be the best intro to IoC Containers (I can't seem to find a good one at the moment), but it's a good read.)

From what I've read they're similar to Factories and are good for instantiating things at run-time.

An SO post that might be of interest: [Dependency Injection vs Factory Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557742/dependency-injection-vs-factory-pattern)

I'm not sure how this would work with getting only a single instance -- I've not used one before, only read about them.